# Initialize value of a text field in a form created by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created one form using ng-repeat. How should I initialize value of a text box ?. I have tested with ng-init 
    ng-init="data.item.rate[$index]=10" and this is working

But I want to initialize with value in items as  ng-init="data.item.rate[$index]={{item.rate}}" but this code not working

```
<ion-list id="item_list" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">

<input   type="text" id="rate_{{ $index }}" name="rate_{{ $index }}" ng-model="data.item.rate[$index]" ng-init="data.item.rate[$index]={{item.rate}}">      

</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not use brackets ({{}}) in ng-init.

```
<ion-list id="item_list" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
   <input   type="text" id="rate_{{ $index }}" name="rate_{{ $index }}" ng-model="data.item.rate[$index]" ng-init="data.item.rate[$index]=item.rate">      
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help